# Python line_num printing the line number outputs only the last line number

Tags: python, loops, csv, readline

I am trying to print the line number of a .csv file, but it outputs ony the last line number on all rows, here is my code:

```
import csv
openfile = open('example_csv.csv')
readcsv = csv.reader(openfile, delimiter = ',')
list_csv_content = list(readcsv)

for row in list_csv_content:
    print(f'Row #{readcsv.line_num} {row}')
```

The output is like this:

```
Row #7 ['4/5/2015 13:34', 'Apples', '73']
Row #7 ['4/5/2015 3:41', 'Cherries', '85']
Row #7 ['4/6/2015 12:46', 'Pears', '14']
Row #7 ['4/8/2015 8:59', 'Oranges', '52']
Row #7 ['4/10/2015 2:07', 'Apples', '152']
Row #7 ['4/10/2015 18:10', 'Bananas', '23']
Row #7 ['4/10/2015 2:40', 'Strawberries', '98']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you save the `readcsv` into a list you are reading the entire csv, that's why the line_num is pointing to the last line.

you can solve it by not saving the csv into a list:

```
openfile = open('test.csv')
readcsv = csv.reader(openfile, delimiter = ',')

for line in readcsv:
    print(line, readcsv.line_num)
```

or by enumerating the list:

```
import csv
openfile = open('example_csv.csv')
readcsv = csv.reader(openfile, delimiter = ',')
list_csv_content = list(readcsv)

for i, row in enumerate(list_csv_content):
    print(f'Row #{i} {row}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `line_num` property is just the total line count that were read by your reader.

The following code should work, however, where you `enumerate` and get the actual line, plus the **zero-based** index of that row.

```py
import csv
openfile = open('chart-images.csv')
readcsv = csv.reader(openfile, delimiter = ',')
list_csv_content = list(readcsv)

for line_num, row in enumerate(list_csv_content): 
    print(f'Row #{line_num} {row}')
```

- Switched to enumerate, as indicated by @vks

Comment: You can also use `enumerate`

Comment: `line_num` is the number of lines read from the iterator, not the total number of lines https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.line_num